# SVN Email Report

Tags: svn

I use subversion.com for my personal stuff and whenever a commit is made I get a detailed report of what exactly changed and who changed it.  I've read a bit into hooks and understand that this is likely a hook but it seems like it's not default functionality included with Subversion.  It sounds like it's something I'm going to have to program... am I correct with that conclusion or can I just "set it up" by entering a few emails?

Please tell me it's included :)

**Update**

This is exactly what I'm looking for... do any of you know where I can find pre-built scripts that do exactly this?

```
$ svn diff
Index: bar.c
===================================================================
--- bar.c (revision 3)
+++ bar.c (working copy)
@@ -1,7 +1,12 @@
+#include <sys/types.h>
+#include <sys/stat.h>
+#include <unistd.h>
+
+#include <stdio.h>
  int main(void) {
-   printf("Sixty-four slices of American Cheese...\n");
+   printf("Sixty-five slices of American Cheese...\n");
  return 0;
  }
Index: README
===================================================================
--- README (revision 3)
+++ README (working copy)
@@ -193,3 +193,4 @@
+Note to self: pick up laundry.
Index: stuff/fish.c
===================================================================
--- stuff/fish.c (revision 1)
+++ stuff/fish.c (working copy)
-Welcome to the file known as 'fish'.
-Information on fish will be here soon.
Index: stuff/things/bloo.h
===================================================================
--- stuff/things/bloo.h (revision 8)
+++ stuff/things/bloo.h (working copy)
+Here is a new file to describe
+things about bloo.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre/post commit hooks functionality you mentioned *are* indeed included. The scripts necessary to generate and send commit emails, however, are not. Google around and you're sure to find a plethora of example, though.

Comment: Such as this Ruby post-commit script: http://gurge.com/blog/2006/09/10/subversion-post-commit-email-hook-in-ruby/

Comment: I'm not quite looking for examples, more of a definite solution that I can merely copy and paste...

Comment: Webnet - the likelihood of you finding a copy/paste solution that does exactly what you want is pretty small. Check out some of the example scripts out there. Perhaps there's one that you *will* be able to copy/paste. If not, figure out what modifications you need to make and see it as a learning experience.